# Unable to run method multiple times

Tags: ruby, wiringpi

I'm using the [WiringPi](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Ruby) gem. This block of code works as expected:

```
pinNumber = 7
io = WiringPi::GPIO.new do |gpio| 
    gpio.pin_mode(pinNumber, WiringPi::INPUT) 
end 

pin_state = io.digital_read(pinNumber) 
return pin_state
```

However, when I enclose this in a method so I can make a call using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), I get the following error when I try to refresh:

> wiringPiSetup*: You must only call this once per program run. This is
>   a fatal error. Please fix your code.

Why must this be run only once, and what is the best solution? Ultimately `pin_state` needs to be retrieved every time I navigate to the root url.

Here's the full code:

```
require 'wiringpi'
require 'sinatra'

def getstate()
    pinNumber = 7
    io = WiringPi::GPIO.new do |gpio|
      gpio.pin_mode(pinNumber, WiringPi::INPUT)
    end     

    pin_state = io.digital_read(pinNumber)
    return pin_state
end 

get '/' do
    getstate()
end
```

Answer (score 2):

After creating your GPIO instance, you can make repeated calls to read pins from it. Your code is creating a new instance on each call, however.

```
require 'wiringpi'
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  InputPin = 7

  IO = WiringPi::GPIO.new do |gpio|
    gpio.pin_mode(InputPin, WiringPi::INPUT)
  end     

  def get_state(pin_number = MyApp::InputPin)
    MyApp::IO.digital_read(pin_number)
  end 

  get '/' do
    get_state
  end
end
```

Comment: This demonstrates good use of Ruby idioms. The constant value InputPin is implemented as .... a constant!

Comment: running this gives me a 404 error, even if i replace the `get_state` with "hello world". some other boilerplate needed perhaps?

Comment: @AaronThomas You've got to require `sinatra/base` for a modular app instead of `sinatra` which is for top-level apps. Also, you might need to adjust the way you access the `get_state` method with this depending on the scope. Sinatra does some hoop jumping that gets confusing. When in doubt, [check the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
pinNumber = 7

def io
    @io ||= begin
        WiringPi::GPIO.new do |gpio|
          gpio.pin_mode(pinNumber, WiringPi::INPUT)
        end
    end
end

def getstate()
    pin_state = io.digital_read(pinNumber)
    return pin_state
end 

get '/' do
    getstate() end
```

Initialize the API once when your application starts (outside getState() method). You're initializing the API multiple times, thus the error.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately when I move that portion of the code outside of the method, I get "undefined local variable or method `io' for #" when I navigate to the url the first time.

Comment: @AaronThomas you need to cache the `io` object outside the method. Initialize the object and save it to a variable, then use the variable inside the `getstate` method. Move the part that is in the `do .. end` block up into the body of the `getstate` method.

Comment: @zetetic I'm not following - could you give an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: @AaronThomas See edited code. ||= is memoization. It basically caches the value of io so that the initialization code block doesn't run every single time. This is assuming pinNumber doesn't change every time?

Comment: `def` statements are scope boundaries, so `pinNumber` is not in-scope inside of `getstate`.